# Ask Ubuntu Data Server - Blazing Fast Searches from the Data Dump and API

Tags: app, data-dump, askubuntu, c++

> **Note:** a special thank-you to [Jacob](https://stackapps.com/users/5758/jacob) for hosting this application on his server.

### Screenshot

http://static.quickmediasolutions.com/media/screenshots/audsmdi.png

### About

This project was born out of a need to get data from the Ask Ubuntu API with little latency. Since the API itself is quite slow (with respect to the `/similar` method in particular) and is not suitable for 'search-as-you-type' requests, it became quite clear that some other form of search was required. None of the major search engines provided what was needed.

Since Ask Ubuntu releases data dumps with most of the site content, the idea for AU Data Server was born. This application would be designed to take advantage of the data dumps and improve performance dramatically by responding to queries within milliseconds. The database would be kept up to date with the API by polling frequently.

In its current state, the server application is set up and running on `http://audata.quickmediasolutions.com`. I have set up a small page that fetches content from the server - the link is below.

### License

GPL v3

### Download

The search demo webpage can be found here:
http://askubuntu.quickmediasolutions.com/

**Note:** the search results are kept up to date using the API. In fact, the server searches through data no older than two minutes - so you can be sure your search gets you the results you're looking for.

### Contact

I can be contacted at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`

### Code

The server is written in C++ using Qt and libcurl and will compile on Windows / Mac / Linux (well, hopefully it will - I only tested on Windows and Linux). The demo page is written in JavaScript using jQuery.

The project is hosted on Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/audataserver