# Stacklense - Ubuntu Unity Lens to search Stack Exchange sites

Tags: app

##Screenshot / Code Snippet

http://iccode.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/stacklense_starting.png

http://iccode.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/stacklense_results.png

The application makes searches in question titles.

Please note that the lens will show only answered questions!

The names of the sites are usually one word, for example Ask Ubuntu becomes askubuntu, all names can be found at https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=default&run=true look for the "api_site_parameter":

Examples

1. search for python django at Stack Overflow site:
   Type: `python django ~~stackoverflow;`
2. search for ppa at Ask Ubuntu site:
   Type: `ppa ~~askubuntu;`
3. search for mac os x lion at Super User site:
   Type: `mac os x lion ~~superuser;`

##About
Stacklense is written with Python 2 (json, cStringIO, urllib2), using Stack Exchange API, Ubuntu Quickly workflow - platform; the code and the personal package archives are hosted at Launchpad.
It is written for people who like to mess with computers - programming languages and all the stuff Stack Exchange and Ubuntu Linux freely provide, with hope that may be useful to someone or hopefully to many out there.

###License
Stacklense is free (as in freedom) software distributed under GNU General Public License v3.

###Download
You can find the ppa at [https://launchpad.net/~iccode/+archive/staclense](https://launchpad.net/%7Eiccode/+archive/staclense), instructions for installation at http://answers.launchpad.net/staclense/+faq/1998

###Platform
Stacklense is written and tested on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit, using the Unity Lenses feature;it will probably work on 32 bit architecture too (i386 build at ppa). There is a package for Ubuntu 12.10 available at Launchpad but not tested.

##Contact

You can reach me using stef[at]iccode.net or at Launchpad. I am the only contributor since it is a small application but anyone can join if has ideas to implement - or wants to tweak the code.

##Code

Python 2.X (default shipped with Ubuntu 12.04) using standard library modules only.
Ubuntu Quickly,
Stack Echange API,
Launchpad (as mentioned above to get the code or to contribute (open for all [may need to contact me first, i am not sure if i need to add you first])

##Made with

[Ubuntu Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly)

[Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)